# what's wrong with this very simple code

Tags: java, if-statement, calculator, iostream

When I run my code, it works right up until it asks the question "which operation do you want to use from ( sum , subst , multi , div )". No matter what the user picks, there is no response from my program!

Why is this happening?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class three3 {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int x;
        int y;
        int opera;
        String oper;

        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println(" write the first number ");
        x = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println(" write the second number ");
        y = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println(" which operation do you want to use from ( sum , subst , multi , div )");
        oper = in.nextLine();

        if (oper == "sum") {
            opera=x+y;
            System.out.println(" the sum of two numbers is " + opera );
        }

        if (oper == "subst") {
            opera = x - y;
            System.out.println(" the subtraction of two numbers is " + opera );
        }

        if (oper == "multi") {
            opera = x * y;
            System.out.println(" the multi of two numbers is " + opera );
        }

        if (oper == "div") {
            opera = x / y;
            System.out.println(" the division of two numbers is " + opera );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because none of those if-clauses is executed.
You're comparing `Strings` with `==` which is wrong. Use `oper.equals("sum")` instead. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus) for reference. The conclusion for you is to always use `equals` for `Strings`.

Comment: This is not the right answer

Comment: @gurghet I missed the bug in Juan's answer but the point I'm adressing is nevertheless a reason for the unexpected behavior.

Comment: there is not a *wrong* response. there is *no* response

Comment: Who said anything about a response?

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `in.nextLine()` right after the last call to `in.nextInt()` The reason is that just asking for the next integer doesn't consume the entire line from the input, and so you need skip ahead to the next new-line character in the input by calling `in.nextLine()`.

```
int y = in.nextInt();
in.nextLine();
```

This pretty much has to be done each time you need to get a new line after calling a method that doesn't consume the entire line, such as when you call `nextBoolean()` etc.

In addition, you don't check for String equality with the `==` operator, use the `.equals()` String method instead.

Comment: this is the right answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `in.nextLine()` consumes the \n inserted implicitly when you clicked enter after the int was entered. That means that the program doesn't expect any other input from the user. To fix this you could consume a new line with `in.nextLine()` before putting it int your actual variable, something like this:

```
System.out.println(" write the second number ");
y=in.nextInt();

System.out.println(" which operation do you want to use from ( sum , subst , multi , div )");

in.nextLine(); //New line consuming the \n

oper=in.nextLine();

if(oper.equals("sum")){//replace == by .equals
   opera=x+y;
}
```

Apart from that, and as runDOSrun said, you should replace the comparisons of strings from `a==b` to `a.equals(b)`

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to other people's points, you should also consider using `else if{}` and `else{}` statements so you can catch invalid input.